# Disabling office file validation in Microsoft Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word

Is there a way to turn off Office File validation in Microsoft Word 2013?

This method that works on Word 2003 and 2007 does not seem to work for word 2013 (The Registry key is not created during the default installation)

> To prevent Office File Validation from validating files you must
>   create the following registry keys & values, and assign a DWORD value
>   of “0” for the specified application in Office 2003 or Office 2007:

Keys:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\<version ie 11.0 or 12.0>\<app eg Word or Excel>\Security\FileValidation
```

Comment: [Plan Protected View settings for Office 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857087.aspx#bypass)

Comment: Office 2013 is v15, and that path they reference (other than the FileValidation key it tells you to create) is there on my install.  So the path would be `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Word\Security\FileValidation` -- What did you try exactly?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 The path HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\ exists on my installation. Anything beyond that does not exist.

Comment: Yeah, that seems odd it's missing.  Have you run any of the Office apps as that user yet?  Exactly which version of Word/Office 2013 are you using?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007  I am using word version 15.0.4805.1001. This user has run office apps as the user.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should have said "edition".  Is this a regular copy, or Office 365?  Was it installed from media (like and Office DVD, or a downloaded ISO, etc.), or was it a Click-To-Run install? 32 or 64-bit Office install?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Its Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013. Not sure if that answers your question